# How to populate cell contents based on entries in the columns from the another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have 2 sheets in excel
1st sheet: 
A1:citibank 
A2:icici 
A3:bankofamerica 

Ctrl + S the excel **then** -->

2nd sheet
A1:citibank B1: (dropdown to select from icici,bankofamerica)
A2:icici B2: (dropdown to select from citibank,bankofamerica)
A3:bankofamerica B3: (dropdown to select from citibank,icici)

How should i go about achieving this ? i am using excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

Use data validation with your 1st sheet:
On your 2nd sheet for B1 select the data ribbon -> data validation -> list -> choose the other 2 banks from you list on Sheet1

Do it for the other 2 cell but each time select another list of 2.

Answer (score 0):

@Rkk, First of all you have not mentioned whether you need a reference from first sheet or not.

As mentioned by Balinti, you can use data validation in second sheet using reference from first sheet. But if use add any row in between or above the data, the reference value may change.

Second approach can be like: go to data ribbon > data validation > list > select option list from allow tab > **"Type in"** source : icici, bankof america (for citibank);

Do the same procedure for other two cells with rest bank names.

Comment: yes i need a reference from 1st sheet. as soon as i SAVE my excel i want those value to be populated in the dropdown for selection in a particular cell of 2nd sheet